# R: Loop through columns, select value from a column and write it to a new column in same row

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have dataframe in following format

```
id   var1  val1 status1 var2 val2 status2 var3 val3 status3 
123  a     12   false   b    23   true    c    34   true
```

Here I want to go though each column of row, get the first occurance of status true for a variable and save it to a new row. Here is the expected output for above example.

Is there a way to do this without using 2 for loops. (loop inside a loop).

```
id   var1  val1 status1 var2 val2 status2 var3 val3 status3 firstOccured
123  a     12   false   b    23   true    c    34   true    b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that it would be easier to work with data in long format. So the first would be to reshape from wide to long

```
dat_long <- reshape(dat, idvar = "id", varying = 2:ncol(dat), direction = "long", sep = "")
```

Assuming that you have more than one group of `id`, you can use `ave` (for the grouping) and `match` (to get the first index of `"true"` in `status`) as follows:

```
dat_long <- transform(dat_long,
                      firstOccured = ave(status, id, FUN = function(x) var[match("true", x)]))
```

Result

```
dat_long
#       id time var val status firstOccured
#123.1 123    1   a  12  false            b
#123.2 123    2   b  23   true            b
#123.3 123    3   c  34   true            b
```

---

If we need to go back to wide format we can do

```
out <- reshape(dat_long, idvar = "id", timevar = "time", direction = "wide", sep = "")
out <- out[setdiff(names(out), c("firstOccured1", "firstOccured2"))]
out
#       id var1 val1 status1 var2 val2 status2 var3 val3 status3 firstOccured3
#123.1 123    a   12   false    b   23    true    c   34    true             b
```

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(id = 123L, var1 = "a", val1 = 12L, status1 = "false", 
    var2 = "b", val2 = 23L, status2 = "true", var3 = "c", val3 = 34L, 
    status3 = "true"), .Names = c("id", "var1", "val1", "status1", 
"var2", "val2", "status2", "var3", "val3", "status3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```